# ¿Cómo implementar un sumatorio en haskell?

Tags: recursión, haskell

tengo que implementar un código que realice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo el siguiente código:

```
module Sigma where
    sigma :: Int -> Int -> Int-> Int
    sigma f a b = f * a + sigma f (a + 1) b
```

El problema lo tengo en cómo parar el bucle. He provado con un if, pero me obligaba a poner un else completamente innecesario.
También me gustaría pedir si saben de alguna página web o pdf que enseñe haskell porque soy nuevo en este lenguaje y tengo bastantes errores.
Un saludo.

Comment: Pedir recomendaciones de libros, o recursos externos es motivo de cierre de preguntas. Te invito a participar en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de [es.so], donde si podrías preguntar este tipo de cosas, pero en particular de Haskell te adelanto que pocos en el sitio (en castellano) lo dominan, y probablemente en el chat sea igual. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ningún momento se indica que tengas que hacer una función recursiva. El modo más rápido de hacer el sumatorio sería:

```hs
sigma :: (Int -> Int) -> Int-> Int
sigma f a b = sum [f i | i <- [a..b]]
```

Pero ya que la dificultad la has tenido con la recursividad, vamos a ver cómo resolverlo.

No entiendo bien cómo has usado el `if..then..else`, pero es evidente que necesita los dos valores que tiene que retornar, según se evalúe la condición.

```hs
sigma :: (Int -> Int) -> Int-> Int
sigma f a b = if a == b then f a else f a + sigma f (a + 1) b
```

En mi experiencia, casi simpre se puede prescindir del if. En este caso, en la definición de la función puedes tener varias definiciones con distintas *"salvaguardas"* de modo que se usará una definición u otra según cumpla las condiciones.

```hs
sigma :: (Int -> Int) -> Int-> Int
sigma f a b
  | a == b = f a
  | otherwise = f a + sigma f (a + 1) b
```

Comment: ¿Qué es otherwise?

Comment: `otherwise` es un _alias_ de `True`. Se usa para dejar claro que se trata de la cláusula por defecto cuando el resto de cláusulas se han evaluado negativamente (`False`). Es algo que encontrarás en la documentación de haskell.